# Covert a days and time column into days colum

Tags: python, datetimepicker

I have a column TRM_LENGTH with values i want to extract the number of days from this column 
                 365 days 05:49:12.000000000

Comment: `365 days 05:49:12.000000000` is the same format in all your rows of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex

```
(\d+) days
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKAL2G/1/) link

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

source = '365 days 05:49:12.000000000'
pattern = r'^(\d+)'
match = re.search(pattern, source)
year = match.group(0)
print(year)
```